# How to instantiate an empty locator in Playwright for Typescript

Tags: typescript, class, playwright

So I'm trying to make a custom selector with my Playwright tests, but I can't figure out how to make an empty locator. The goal of this is to pass in a string of test IDs to get a nested element, this is just to make things more readable in my tests.
The goal is something like this:

```js
export class CustomPage {
   protected readonly page: Page;
   
   constructor(page: Page) {
      this.page = page;
   }

   public getNestedElement(testIds: Array<string>) {
      let locator = //instantiate locator with this.page

      foreach(const id of testIds) {
         locator = locator.getByTestId(id);
      }

      return locator;
   }
}
```

Thank you for any help you can offer!

Comment: This seems [unusual to want to do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/399876). An empty locator makes no sense. I'm not sure why you're doing this, but if you provide a bit more context, surely there's a better way to do whatever it is you're trying to do. The loop here is pointless--it'd just set and return the last `locator` in `testIds`. But that also makes no sense because you can't use `for .. of` over a string in the first place. Can you clarify the fundamental goal, requirements and code? Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen It's meant to get a nested element in a more readable way. The loop is meant to appened the next locator to the last locator (ex: page.getByTestId('').getByTestId('')). As for the for loop; that's actually meant to be a string array, a typo on my part.

Comment: Why not query for the nested element directly, using a single locator? Is the component recursive? Test ids aren't generally considered good practice to begin with. There's probably a better way to select whatever you're trying to select. If you don't mind showing the element and providing full context, someone can probably provide a cleaner way to access it than using unusual patterns like this.

Comment: @ggorlen referencing the nested element directly would result in several different elements being referenced. I don't have control over whether or not I use a test id, as I'm doing this for work and this is their preferred way.

Answer (score 2):

What you seem to be asking for is possible:

```
public getNestedElementByTestIds(testIds: Array<string>) {
  if (testIds.length === 0) {
    throw Error("testIds must contain at least one element");
  }

  let locator = this.page.getByTestId(testIds[0]);

  for (const testId of testIds.slice(1)) {
    locator = locator.getByTestId(testId);
  }

  return locator;
}
```

Runnable example:

```js
const playwright = require("playwright"); // ^1.30.1

const html = `
<div data-testid="foo">
  ignore this
  <div data-testid="bar">
    ignore this
    <div data-testid="baz">
      ignore this
      <div data-testid="quux">
        PRINT ME
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>`;

const getNestedElementByTestIds = (page, testIds) => {
  if (testIds.length === 0) {
    throw Error("testIds must contain at least one element");
  }

  let locator = page.getByTestId(testIds[0]);

  for (const testId of testIds.slice(1)) {
    locator = locator.getByTestId(testId);
  }

  return locator;
}

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await playwright.chromium.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setContent(html);
  console.log((await getNestedElementByTestIds(page, [
    "foo", "bar", "baz", "quux"
  ]).textContent()).trim()); // => PRINT ME
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Caveat emptor: This may be too clever. I would rather chain 2-3 `getByTestIds` in the caller, or use a more robust selection mechanism than test ids and rely on direct, [user visible](https://playwright.dev/docs/best-practices#test-user-visible-behavior) properties.

In general, I'm not eager to abstract Playwright calls into helpers if it's avoidable, even at the cost of some duplication across tests. They're already quite high-level. Anything more than a simple [POM](https://playwright.dev/docs/pom) may become challenging to maintain for anyone but the author.

Comment: I had thought about this solution, but I thought maybe there was a better way. There doesn't seem to be a better way, though. Thank you for the help!